# Magento2: How to create a Ui Component Form in the storefront

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, forms

I am trying to create a form using Ui Components in the storefront.

For that I have created the following:

**A Layout:** that I used to call the Form Component.

```
<!-- magento/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_productclass_assign.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="customer.account.product.classes.assign.listing.header" template="Vendor_ModuleName::assign/header.phtml"/>

            <!-- here is how I call the Ui Component -->
            <uiComponent name="product_classes_assign_listing_form"/>
            <!-- here is how I call the Ui Component -->

            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Dashboard" name="customer.account.link.back" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**The Ui Component Form**

```
<!-- // magento/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/ui_component/product_classes_assign_listing_form.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">product_classes_assign_listing_form.product_classes_assign_listing_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign Product Form</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Assign\Form\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="back">
                <url path="*/*/"/>
                <class>back</class>
                <label translate="true">Back</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>product_classes_assign_listing_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>product_classes_assign_listing_form.product_classes_assign_listing_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="product_classes_assign_listing_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="sample/sample/sample"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Assign\Form\DataProvider" name="product_classes_assign_listing_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
                <requestFieldName>entity_id</requestFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="assign_products">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true" />
        </settings>

        <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
        <field name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">contact</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="name" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
            </settings>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**A DataProvider**

```
<?php
// magento/app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Ui/DataProvider/Assign/Form/DataProvider.php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Assign\Form;

use Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Assign\Listing\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @param string            $name
     * @param string            $primaryFieldName
     * @param string            $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array             $meta
     * @param array             $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }

        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        $this->loadedData = [];

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->loadedData[$item->getId()]['item'] = $item->getData();
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

And defined a **collection** in the DI to be used as a data source

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product_classes_assign_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Assign\Listing\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**The Problem:** The form renders and I can see the fields BUT the buttons do not show.

Also, this renders a blank form and that is fine to add new information BUT (let say I also want to edit information using this form), how can I tell the form the ids of the row I want to edit?